# Zabbix - Create Trigger that parse the time in a file

Tags: centos, zabbix

I have a file that is written on each of my Zabbix clients with a time inside of it every hour.

I need the Zabbix server(s) to check these files and alert if the time is at least 6 hours old.

I cannot see where or how this trigger might be implemented and the Zabbix documentation does not give me enough detail.

Comment: Could you please describe what time format is used inside the files? Can you change it, if need be?

Comment: Currently the time format inside the file is HHMMSS, but as the file is generated via a Ruby script this could be anything that would help Zabbix read it more easily.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to output Unix timestamp into the file and read that value using vfs.file.contents[] (see [item documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent)). This has the benefit that you can specify "unixtime" as the unit in [item configuration](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/items/item) and you will see a pretty value in "Latest data".

A trigger could then be as follows:

```
{host:vfs.file.contents[/tmp/timestamp.txt].now()} -
    {host:vfs.file.contents[/tmp/timestamp.txt].last()} > 6h
```